# R package corrplot - headmap color and lower triangular variable names

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have two questions concerning the package `corrplot`:

1) How do I make the colors of the headmap contrast more? Everything in the range from -0.2 to 0.2 is hardly visible.

2) I want just half of the correlation matrix. If I change the type to "lower" the variable names come down. However I still want them to be up, like a regular rectangle.

[Attached as screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukNR7.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is good practice to add a reproducible example to your question. Show us the code of how you produced the screenshot instead of the screenshot. That will make it easier to help you and more likely that you will receive useful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the documentation of `corrplot` there are several examples of how to change color scales. It's easy to create your own color scales. Here's just one possible example:

```
require(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
col <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))
corrplot(M, col = col(10))
```

2) You can easily change the position of the labels and the color scale using the arguments `tl.pos` and `cl.pos` respectively. For example:

```
corrplot(M, col = col(10), type = "lower", cl.pos = "r", tl.pos = "lt")
```